# How to generate a special numpy 1D array quickly?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, python-3.5

I want to generate a numpy 1D array like this:

1. number 0 repeated n_0 times
2. number 1 repeated n_1 times
3. number 2 repeated n_2 times
4. ...
5. number N repeat n_N times

The n_1, n_2, n_3, ... n_N are different and N can be very big.

Here I randomly generate an array `nv=[n_1, n_2, ...,n_N]` to show the method I can use at present:

`nv = np.random.randint(3, 10+1, size=(1000000,))
np.concatenate([i*np.ones((j,)) for i,j in zip(range(1000000), nv)])`

So my question is: there is a better way to do such thing?

I have another question about 1D numpy array generation, please see:
[How to generate a 1D numpy array like [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, …]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310119/how-to-generate-a-1d-numpy-array-like-0-1-2-3-0-1-2-3-4-0-1-2-0-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's literally a function for this:

```
numpy.repeat(numbers_to_repeat, numbers_of_repetitions)
```

If by "number 0", "number 1", etc., you mean the natural numbers starting from 0, and not the elements of some input array, that'd be

```
numpy.repeat(numpy.arange(N), numbers_of_repetitions)
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks very much!

Comment: I appended a new similar question into above question, can you give me more suggestions? Thanks