# Generate 1D NumPy array of concatenated ranges

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.5

I want to generate a following array `a`:

```
nv = np.random.randint(3, 10+1, size=(1000000,))
a = np.concatenate([np.arange(1,i+1) for i in nv])
```

Thus, the output would be something like -

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, ...]
```

Does there exist any better way to do it?

Comment: Typo -  `np.range` should be `np.arange`, I believe.

Comment: `np.r_[:4, :5, :3, :6]`  is a nice compact way of generating such an array 'by-hand'.  It doesn't offer any advantages if starting with a `nv` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using `cumulative summation` -

```
def ranges(nv, start = 1):
    shifts = nv.cumsum()
    id_arr = np.ones(shifts[-1], dtype=int)
    id_arr[shifts[:-1]] = -nv[:-1]+1
    id_arr[0] = start # Skip if we know the start of ranges is 1 already
    return id_arr.cumsum()
```

Sample runs -

```
In [23]: nv
Out[23]: array([3, 2, 5, 7])

In [24]: ranges(nv, start=0)
Out[24]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [25]: ranges(nv, start=1)
Out[25]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [62]: nv = np.random.randint(3, 10+1, size=(100000,))

In [63]: %timeit your_func(nv) # @MSeifert's solution
10 loops, best of 3: 129 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit ranges(nv)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.54 ms per loop
```

Comment: oh so much faster, now I have to upvote your answer (even though I don't fully understand the _magic_ `id_arr[shifts[:-1]] = -nv[:-1]+1` line)

Comment: @MSeifert Yeah, not straight-forward. Might explain later on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this with numpy methods you could use normal python `range`s and just convert the result to an array:

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

def your_func(nv):
    ranges = (range(1, i+1) for i in nv)
    flattened = list(chain.from_iterable(ranges))
    return np.array(flattened)
```

This doesn't need to utilize hard to understand numpy slicings and constructs. To show a sample case:

```
import random

>>> nv = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(5)]
>>> print(nv)
[4, 2, 10, 5, 3]

>>> print(your_func(nv))
[ 1  2  3  4  1  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why two steps?

```
a = np.concatenate([np.arange(0,np.random.randint(3,11)) for i in range(1000000)])
```

Comment: I believe the first step was just to create a sample input.

Comment: Yes, it is just a sample input.

Comment: Got it.  Well, I guess I'll leave this here in case anyone else didn't realize that the problem was to build the range array from an existing list of lengths.